# Shortest path to nearest... something

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, distance

I have a list of addresses and a map including train stations, schools etc., and I would like to calculate the ***shortest*** distance from each address to the ***nearest*** train station, school etc.

I'm aware that the `google maps API` can calculate the shortest distance to any specific point, but my problem is complicated by the fact that I also need to find the nearest train station etc. Is there an easy way to do this in QGIS?

- I use QGIS
- Windows 7 64bit

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please check out http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/shortest%20paths/ and this http://gis-lab.info/qa/road-graph-eng.html it may help.

Comment: I think the solution you propose is good if one is doing 1 to 1 routing,meaning that, you already know your origin or destination. The user in fact wants a routing problem where they have to route through all the nodes in the graph and for each node determine the nearest neighbour.

Comment: Thanks for the links. As @dassouki mentions they only seem to calculate the shortest path to a point of interest, where I need the shortest path to nearest point of interest. I guess I can just calculate the shortest path to every point of interest, and then determine which is nearest, but I was hoping for a plugin to do that for me.